# How did we find relative atomic masses in 18th century or early 19th century?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry, atoms, mole

The atomic masses of atoms or relative atomic masses were known in the 19th century.

But how did they actually calculate that relative atomic mass?

What I think is that if we have a sample of an element, let's say carbon, then we can find its atomic mass by dividing the total mass of the sample by total number of atoms in it.
But how could we find the number of carbon atoms in a sample?

(We are in early 19th century)
How could we do this job of finding number of atoms in a sample to find the atomic mass?

Comment: Aside of the referred question, eventually more relevant is the StackExchange site [History of science and mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Before the widespread use of spectroscopic methods, the preparation of derivatives for the qualitative and quantitative analysis was much more common. E.g., carefully executed reactions to solute ores, separate ions by adjustment of pH and eventual precipitation (gravimetric analysis). Changes of masses were monitored closely by precision balances. But you can't miss Morley still recognized today for his contributions in this field, especially to establish a reference [on oxygen](https://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/education/whatischemistry/landmarks/atomicweightofoxygen.html).

Comment: The reason i used the term early 19th century is to eliminate the answers that use atomic numbers and no. of neutrons in nucleus to calculate its mass. Also people may say that hydrogen is 12 times lighter than carbon-12 but my question is how do we know that?